# Magento2.4 order grid status color

Tags: grid, admin-panel, order-status, order-grid, magento2.4

I want to add color to order grid on magento2.4 admin panel, sales -> orders.
Each status should have own color, forexample status "complete" shows purple and all rows who has complete status become purple

Answer (score 0):

Please add custom js file in sales_order_index.xml file and to color completed order grid row as per the value,I have written below code in js file :

```
require(["jquery"], function($){

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var i = setInterval(function ()
    {
        if ($('.data-grid-cell-content').length)
        {
            //clearInterval(i);
            $('.data-grid-cell-content').each(function(i, obj) {
                var classStatusName = $(this).text();
                if (classStatusName == "Complete")
                {
                    $(this).closest('tr').addClass("class-purple");
                }

            });
        }
    }, 100);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install module: [Magento 2 Grid Colors](https://github.com/shkoliar/magento-grid-colors)**

**Refer [link](https://youtu.be/eJ1ZgUQ_S4U) to watch the youtube video.**